# Parsing a JSON with Javascript yields undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am hitting a test API I built with `jQuery` which gives me a `JSON`.

In my `Javascript`, I am doing the following:

```
var myjson = (getData['responseJSON']['results']);
console.log(myjson);
```

This yields the below results:

```
{"A":{"0":1,"1":2},"B":{"0":2,"1":3},"C":{"0":3,"1":4}}
```

I would like to instead just return the values for A, which I assumed would just be like below. But when I do this I get `undefined`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var myjson = (getData['responseJSON']['results']['A']);
console.log(myjson);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var myjson = JSON.parse(getData['responseJSON']['results']);
console.log(myjson['A']);`